# Site Creation using SharePoint

Tags: site-collection, upgrade, branding

If you decide to move your Intranet to the SharePoint 2013, which tools do you use to design your home page?

I mean do you create Site Collection through Central Administration? If I desire to design the first page as a proper website with feeds, tabs to sub sites, news and etc how should I do that?

P.s. A site similar to this for example: http://www.wssdemo.com/Intranets/Commwealth%20Bank.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can provision your site through either Central Administration or PowerShell (if you have a lot sometimes it makes more sense to script them).

Since you're talking about upgrading, I'm assuming you're currently on SharePoint 2010, but your post isn't clear there. From a design perspective, you need to really think about what your plans are. Much like when we upgraded 2007 to 2010, upgrading 2010 to 2013 will result in some design rework if you want the 2013 look and feel. You certainly could upgrade to 2013 and keep the old 2010 ribbon instead of the 2013 look, but typically if you're going to upgrade you want to take advantage of all of the capability. It likely makes more sense to focus on designing a 2013 masterpage to deploy to your newly upgraded farm, rather than design something for 2010 and trying to upgrade it.

While it's *possible* to modify your masterpages and page layouts in SharePoint Designer, that is definitely not a best practice from either an implementation or maintainability perspective. The best practice approach is to develop your custom masterpages and page layouts, package them into a Visual Studio solution, and deploy that solution to your farm.

Comment: No we are not on 2010 but we have an existing website but we are going to put that aside and switch to the SharePoint 2013. I tried the Team Site and some other pages, but what I am looking for is a homepage that based on the location of users will be directed to each locations sub page.

Comment: You'll likely need to do some custom development if you want to automatically route users to a specific page based on location. If you have that information in UPS it's likely a lot easier to achieve, but still would require custom development.

Comment: no not automatically. I want to have a public face page which all users can see containing news, feeds, ... and then give them the choice to select their location and see their own site page.

Comment: So in this way, users do not need to be authorized until they want to see their own site page.

Comment: That would be native, out of the box capability then.